# ggplot2 plot every column of a data frame against every other column

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Lets say i have the following data frame:

```
A       B       C       
0.451   0.333   0.034           
0.491   0.270   0.033     
0.389   0.249   0.084   
0.425   0.819   0.077  
0.457   0.429   0.053       
0.436   0.524   0.049
```

I am wondering if there is a convenient function in ggplot2, that allows me to plot every column of the data frame against every other column in the same plot, so A vs B, A vs C, B vs. C.
Using the `par(mfrow)` argument and plot the individual seems very time consuming, especially if you have a larger data frame.

The result should idealy look something like this, but in stead of the colors which corresponed to the correlation there should just be a scatterplot.

[image]

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: ggpairs might be helpful here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GGally/versions/1.4.0/topics/ggpairs

Answer (score 0):

You can use either ggpairs (as @timfaber suggested) or pairs in base R, if you just want to quickly explore the data.

Your data:

```
x=structure(list(A = c(0.451, 0.491, 0.389, 0.425, 0.457, 0.436
), B = c(0.333, 0.27, 0.249, 0.819, 0.429, 0.524), 
C = c(0.034, 0.033, 0.084, 0.077, 0.053, 0.049)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

For ggpairs, simply do:

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(x)
```

[image]

For pairs in base R, you define a function for the upper panel (to show correlation):

```
panel.cor <- function(x, y, ...)
{
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  txt <- as.character(round(cor(x, y), digits=2))
  text(0.5,0.5, txt)
}
pairs(x, upper.panel=panel.cor)
```

[image]